# How do I call the sum of a tuple list?

Tags: function, f#, sum

I have made a tuple-list, but I can't seem to find the sum of the lists. Do I need to make a function for the sum, or can I call each list `fst` `snd` in the sum code?

```
let (startBoard : board) = ([0; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3], [0; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3])
```

How do I find the sum of the lists? I tried to make a sum function and to call `fst` and `snd` but can't seem to make it work...

```
let sum1 (fst : int list) : int = 
let s = List.sum fst
```

Hope I made my self clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know exactly what the 'board' type is, but this should work.

```
let sum (b: board) = List.sum (fst b), List.sum (snd b)
```

Answer (score 1):

`fst` is a built-in function that returns the first item of a tuple of size two. Your example `sum1` function is naming its first parameter as `fst` which is probably not what you want.

Try something like this:

```
let sum1 (startBoard : board) = List.sum (fst startBoard)
```

And with the power of currying, this can be shortened:

```
let sum1 = List.sum << fst
```